# How can we describe T<S> as return type for a method using generics in java

Tags: java, generics

How can we describe `T<S>` as return type for a method

```
<T,S> T<S> getResult(Class<T> tClass, Class<S> sClass)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't, basically. There's no way of describing "a generic type with one type parameter" and using it like this.

Answer (score 4):

Jon's right in that you can't do this in the general case.  But if we think of a more specific case, say returning a specific type of `List` of a specific type of elements, we can do something like this:

```
<T, L extends List<T>> L getResult(Class<T> tClass, Class<L> lClass)
```

But then there's the problem of calling it.  Classes are parameterized by raw types only.  So if we wanted to call it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> result = getResult(String.class, ArrayList.class);
```

It wouldn't work, because `ArrayList.class` has type `Class<ArrayList>`, not `Class<ArrayList<String>>`.

But then we could use the [super type token](http://gafter.blogspot.ca/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) pattern, which Guava makes really easy with its [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) class:

```
<T, L extends List<T>> L getResult(Class<T> tClass, TypeToken<L> lType) {
   // use lType.getRawType()...
}

ArrayList<String> result = 
    getResult(String.class, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){});
```

Of course, this is only going to be of use if `L` represents a concrete class.  It's also possible to create a `TypeToken` using type parameters, which won't help you at runtime.